# PostgreSQL: Change log file location

Tags: postgresql, logs

How can I change the location of the log file in PostgreSQL? Can it be done without stopping the cluster?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

re 1) See the chapter "Where to log" in the manual.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHERE

You want to change the `log_directory` property.

re 2) No, you need to restart Postgres when you change this.